# Find Integral of $\int\frac{(x^n - x^m)^2}{\sqrt{x}}$ where $n$ and $m$ are natural numbers

Tags: integration

I have tried a couple of ways to do this problem like simplifying and integrating in standard ways, as well as looking at integration by reduction. In the first way, I seem to get nothing meaningful and in the second way I get a bit lost. Would appreciate any hints. After I complete the answer I will write it up on this page.

Comment: **Hint** Expand the square in the top, and then write the integrand as a sum of power functions $x^a$.

Answer (score 1):

First use the substitution

$$x = {t^2}$$

Then regarding to

$$dx = 2tdt$$

your integral becomes

$$\eqalign{
  & \int {{{{{\left( {{t^{2n}} - {t^{2m}}} \right)}^2}} \over t}2tdt}  = \int {2{{\left( {{t^{2n}} - {t^{2m}}} \right)}^2}dt}  = \int {2\left( {{t^{4n}} - 2{t^{2\left( {m + n} \right)}} + {t^{4m}}} \right)dt}   \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = 2\left( {{{{t^{4n + 1}}} \over {4n + 1}} - 2{{{t^{2\left( {m + n} \right) + 1}}} \over {2(m + n) + 1}} + {{{t^{4m + 1}}} \over {4m + 1}}} \right) + C \cr} $$

Comment: The substitution $x=t^2$ is not needed.

Comment: Depending on your will! It just makes things look easier! But can do it without substituion.

Comment: Easier? How? Integrating $t^{4n}$ or $x^{2n-1/2}$ are exactly as easy, no?

Comment: OK! It's just a matter of taste! :)